# using len argument to getline( &buff, &len, f ) for comparison after its call causes it to crash on next call

Tags: c, malloc, getline, realloc

The below error is given only on the second iteration through the loop.

```
sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

This is the relevant part of the loop.

```
   char *buff = NULL ;
   size_t len ;
   size_t cnt = 0 ;


while( getline( &buff, &len, f ) > 1 )
   {

      // fprintf(stderr, "help1\n");
      // We read a last name (with the newline)
      person *p = malloc(sizeof(person)); // - get memory for person

      for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
          p->first[i]=buff[i];
      }
      p->first[len-1]='\0';
```

Changing the comparison to

```
for (int i=0; i<strlen(buff); i++)
```

Causes the issue to disappear. Does anyone know why this happens? p->first does seem to allocate correctly as you can print it after the loop has completed.

Comment: What leads you to believe that the length of the buffer allocated by `getline()` is the same as the length of the string that `getline()` read?

Comment: I guess that's not actually guaranteed anywhere. So this is just incorrect usage then.

Comment: `len` gives you the length of the buffer, not the length of the string.  This is probably longer than the size of the buffer you've allocated in `person` (which you don't show), so the crash comes from running off the end of that malloc'd block

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your posted code does not show the definition of `person`. Therefore, we have for example no way of knowing if `p->first` is a pointer or an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues with your code.

The big one is what is len? How is it defined? What does it represent? I am assuming that len is the length of the buffer, and it is not correct to use that in the loop comparison.  There is no guarantee that the string is going to fill the buffer every time.  There's a couple of ways you can solve this.

```
while( getline( &buff, &len, f ) > 1 )
   {
      char ch;

      // fprintf(stderr, "help1\n");
      // We read a last name (with the newline)
      person *p = malloc(sizeof(person)); // - get memory for person

      for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
          ch = buff[i];
          p->first[i]=ch;
          if (ch == 0x00) break;
      }
      // p->first[len-1]='\0';
```

A second way to solve it is this:

```
while( getline( &buff, &len, f ) > 1 )
   {
      size_t x = strlen(buff);
      // fprintf(stderr, "help1\n");
      // We read a last name (with the newline)
      person *p = malloc(sizeof(person)); // - get memory for person

      for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
          p->first[i]=buff[i];
      }
      p->first[len-1]='\0';
```

I personally like the first method because I think it's more efficient.  It will copy at most len bytes, but if it encounters the terminating null before that, it will break out of the loop.  The comparison is done *AFTER* the copy so if it is a null, the null will have been copied before the loop is terminated.

The second method calls strlen then enters the loop, so you are running two loops (strlen is implemented using a while loop).  So the first method is basically a strlen and strncpy combined into one loop.

Answer (score 0):

What leads you to believe that the length of the buffer allocated by getline() is the same as the length of the string that getline() read? – Andrew Henle

Comment: Indeed it can't be, as it must be at least 1 byte larger to hold the NUL terminator.  It might be significantly larger.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely that you've allocated a fixed size char array in your `struct person` (which you fail to show the declaration of) and you're running off the end of that.  Try something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < len && i < sizeof(p->first)-1; ++i)
    p->first[i] = buff[i];
p->first[sizeof(p->first) - 1] = '\0';
```

to make sure you don't exceed the size of the array in `struct person`